# $2$ square matrices with equal rank

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are $n\times n$ matrices of real numbers such that

- $P^2=P$
- $Q^2=Q$
- $I−P−Q$ is invertible, where $I$ is a $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Show that $P$ and $Q$ have the same rank.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $$rank(P)=rank(P(I-P-Q)),\\rank(Q)=rank((I-P-Q)Q)$$